# Spring singelton per request access from all threads

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, static, singleton

We are using spring for dependency injection but web service is running on the different custom framework. 
While processing request service makes a lot of async calls to other dependencies such as dbs and other apis.

**Problem:**

I need to capture any object, anywhere in a code and have access to all captured objects from any other place **during one single request**. Note that one request spins off many other threads and that `global storage` where I store all captured objects has to be accessible and visible from parent and child threads.

Also, I am not allowed to change existing code or pass any parameters in functions. I need to have some sort of `singleton` with a global context where I can update it from anywhere and any child thread still can access and modify it.

**Important:** Lifecycle of that `global storage` has to be per request. In other words, I want that object to be collected by garbage collector everytime request has finished.

Idea:
My idea is to create something like log4j where I import it on the top of class and use it to capture an object.
e.g

```
@Autowire
private GlobalStorage storage;

public void doSomething(){
   Object obj = getObjc();
   storage.add(obj);
}
```

**Question:**
What would be your recommendations on implementation of `GlobalStorage`? Do I need to make it `InheritableThreadLocal`? How do I make that to be unique per request and erase all data after the request has finished?

Thanks!

Comment: What you describe seems completely impossible to me.

Comment: @JBNizet why do you think it is impossible?

Comment: To be more accurate, it's possible if you indeed spawn new threads at every request, using an InheritableThreadLocal. But spawning threads is a bad idea most of the time. If you *reuse* threads (as it's generally advised) of a thread pool, and don't pass anything to the tasks submitted to these threads, I don't see how the task could know where to find the state associated to the request, since you don't want to pass anything identifying the request, or the state, to these tasks.

Comment: @JBNizet, what I was thinking is that it is possible to handle that on spring level somehow. What if I create InheritableThreadLocal static object, do you think that could work?